# Why doesn't Spring Boot JPA & Postgresql save entity when used with Neo4J?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot application which uses JPA & Postgresql to persist an entity on program start if it doesn't already exist.  The application also uses Spring Data Neo4J.  When I call save() on the entity in run(), I can see that no entity has been created.  Yet when I use the same code from a REST controller, the entity is created.  If I remove all parts of Spring Data Neo4J, the entity is created in run(). What's wrong please?

My entity class:

```
@Entity
public class PersistentConfig {

    // ------------------------
    // PRIVATE FIELDS
    // ------------------------

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean hasBeenInitialised;

    // ------------------------
    // PUBLIC METHODS
    // ------------------------

    protected PersistentConfig() {}

    public PersistentConfig(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.hasBeenInitialised= false;
    }

    public PersistentConfig(Boolean hasBeenInitialised) {
        this.hasBeenInitialised = hasBeenInitialised;
    }

    // Getters and setters methods
    // ...

    Boolean getHasBeenInitialised() {
        return hasBeenInitialised
    }

    void setHasBeenInitialised(Boolean hasBeenInitialised) {
        this.hasBeenInitialised = hasBeenInitialised
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: ${id}, hasBeenInitialised: ${hasBeenInitialised}"
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
interface PersistentConfigRepository extends CrudRepository<PersistentConfig, Long> {

}
```

Within the main application class:

```
@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    init()
}

public void init() {

    if (persistentConfigRepository.count() == 0) {
        try {
            PersistentConfig pc = new PersistentConfig(false);
            System.out.println("Created PersistentConfig: ${pc}");
            def rc = persistentConfigRepository.save(pc);
            System.out.println(rc)
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error creating the PersistentConfig: " + ex.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("PersistentConfig succesfully created, repo count = ${persistentConfigRepository.count()}");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("PersistentConfig already exists");

    }

}

static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
```

This is what I get in the output when the program launches:

```
Created PersistentConfig: id: 0, hasBeenInitialised: false
id: 24, hasBeenInitialised: false
PersistentConfig succesfully created, repo count = 0
```

If the same code within `init()` is used within a controller, the entity is created and persisted.  Something in JPA is creating the entity within `init()`, as the `id` is incrementing (you can see I've run the program a few times...), but it's just not going into the database (count on the repository is zero and when I inspect the table, there's nothing there).

EDIT to show relevant log including hibernate log statements:

```
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from persistent_config persistent0_
Created PersistentConfig: id: 0, hasBeenInitialised: false
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
id: 28, hasBeenInitialised: false
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from persistent_config persistent0_
PersistentConfig succesfully created, repo count = 0
```

EDIT 2: I've ascertained that the code works when I remove all the Spring Data Neo4J code.  Do I need to do something with a DataSource bean or something?

Comment: can you tell what query you see on console after `save`?

Comment: I've added these to the question - I can't see that there's an insert going on, just a select.

Comment: Does the code need to be wrapped up in a transaction, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, having narrowed down the issue to some form of conflict between JPA and Spring Data Neo4J, I found an answer here: [How to get Spring Data Neo4j and Spring Data JPA to work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749747/how-to-get-spring-data-neo4j-and-spring-data-jpa-to-work-together)

I added these 2 beans into the main application:

```
@Autowired
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

@Override
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager() throws Exception {
    return new ChainedTransactionManager(new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject()),
            new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(graphDatabaseService()).getObject());
}
```